# Jetpack Compose - Can't change AlertDialog white window background

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm new to Kotlin Multiplatform Desktop development and I'm using Compose to build UI. I have one AlertDialog with custom, rounded background, problem is, it still has white corners which I can not remove for some reasons. The dialog:

[image]

The code I've written to achieve this:

```
 AlertDialog(
        title = { Text("თქვენ ტოვებთ პროგრამას") },
        text = { Text("ნამდვილად გსურთ პროგრამიდან გასვლა?") },
        onDismissRequest = {},
        backgroundColor = Colors.DARKER_GRAY,
        contentColor = Colors.WHITE,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
        confirmButton = {
            TextButton(onClick = onPositiveClick) {
                Text(text = "დიახ", color = Colors.RED)
            }
        },
        dismissButton = {
            TextButton(onClick = onNegativeClick) {
                Text(text = "არა", color = Colors.LIGHTER_GRAY)
            }
        },
        modifier = Modifier.defaultMinSize(300.dp).border(0.dp, Color.Transparent, RoundedCornerShape(0))
    )
```

Anyone has any idea how can I solve this? Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

გაუმარჯოს! Try to add the same shape size to Modifier's border as you applied to Dialog's shape:

```
modifier = Modifier.defaultMinSize(300.dp).border(0.dp, Color.Transparent, RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
```

Or you just remove it. The AlertDialogs come without borders.

Perhaps there might be difference between Android and Desktop and you really need that.

At least from Android point of view that's not necessary.

წარმატება!

Answer (score 0):

If I may ask you, is that the preview because if I wrap your code in a column and change its background colour and runs it, it works perfectly okay.

[image: Dialog in column]

```
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Red),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
///Your code is here
        AlertDialog(
            title = { Text("თქვენ ტოვებთ პროგრამას") },
            text = { Text("ნამდვილად გსურთ პროგრამიდან გასვლა?") },
            onDismissRequest = {},
            backgroundColor = Color.Gray,
            contentColor = Color.White,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
            confirmButton = {
                TextButton(onClick = { /*onPositiveClick*/ }) {
                    Text(text = "დიახ", color = Color.Red)
                }
            },
            dismissButton = {
                TextButton(onClick = { /*onNegativeClick*/ }) {
                    Text(text = "არა", color = Color.LightGray)
                }
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .defaultMinSize(300.dp)
                .border(0.dp, Color.Transparent, RoundedCornerShape(0))
        )
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it's working fine but on Android. but now I'm developing desktop app with KMM Desktop and I copy-pasted your code but it does the same

Comment: Okay. Thanks for pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is related to the native android theme color.
Just change background color on your theme:

```xml
<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
```